# How to put a loading animation between scenes

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, loading

I wanted to put a loading animation between scenes. 
I have used

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCBReader sceneWithNodeGraphFromFile:@"SongScene.ccbi"] ];
```

for load the second scene.First scene is a kind of song selection menu. It takes a little delay to load the SongsScene because of the graphic loading time.
Then user is not noticing whether the scene is loading or not. 
Is there a way to display animation while the second scene is loading.

Comment: I think you asked this before. It's a relatively broad question. The easy solution is to present another scene before the one that takes long to load, so you can display a static image or text. To animate, you'd have to put in more work, using the async texture loading capability of cocos2d (assuming as usual that texture loading is 90% of the loading time).

Comment: Thanks @LearnCocos2D. can you explain more on async capability.